# PowerShell script to delete files not in reference file

Tags: windows, powershell, guid

A system put in place by one of our developers caused files attached to emails to be copied to our server over and over again.

It appends a unique GUID to the front of the file name and has caused some 35,000 duplicates with different GUID's.

I have a list of all the files we want to keep, but need a script to reference this file and delete all files that are not in this reference file.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does the list of filenames that you want to keep use the filenames appended with the GUIDs, or the original filenames (i.e. not appended with GUID).

Answer (score 0):

There were some details missing from your description, so here are my assumptions:

Appended files follow a form similar to this:

```
62dc92e2-67b0-437e-ba06-bcbf922f48e8file14.txt
66e7cbb3-873a-429b-b4c3-46597b5b5828file2.txt
68c426a3-49b9-4a80-a3e8-ef73ac875791file13.txt
etc.
```

Your list of files that you want to keep looks something like this:

```
file1.txt
file12.txt
file9.txt
file5.txt
```

**Code:**

```
# list of files you want to keep
$keep = get-content 'keep.txt'

# directory containing files
$guidfiles = get-childitem 'c:\some\directory'

# loop through each filename from the target directory
foreach($guidfile in $guidfiles) {
    $foundit = 0;

    # loop through each of the filenames that you want to keep 
    # and check for a match
    foreach($keeper in $keep) {
        if($guidfile -match "$keeper$") {
            write-output "$guidfile matches $keeper"

            # set flag that indicates we don't want to delete file
            $foundit = 1
            break
        }
    }

    # if flag was not set (i.e. no match to list of keepers) then 
    # delete it
    if($foundit -eq 0) {
        write-output "Deleting $guidfile"

        # As a sanity test, I'd suggest you comment out the line below when 
        # you first run the script.  The output to stdout will tell you which 
        # files would get deleted.  Once you're satisfied that the output
        # is correctly showing the files you want deleted, then you can 
        # uncomment the line and run it for real.
        remove-item $guidfile.fullname
    }
}
```

**Other Considerations:**
You mentioned that this "has caused some 35000 duplicates".  That sounds like the same file may have been copied more than once.  This means that you might also want to remove duplicates of files that you want to keep, so that you just have one.  I couldn't tell for sure from your description if that was true, or not, but the script could be modified to do that, as well.